# creating a parcelable object in kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, parcelable

Best way to create a parcelable object in kotlin?

Answer (score 7):

TestActivity.kt

```
class TestActivity : Activity() {  
    val DEVOTIONAL_RESPONSE: String = "DEVOTIONAL_RESPONSE"
    var holdr: Holdr_ActivityTest? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
        holdr = Holdr_ActivityTest(findViewById(android.R.id.content))

        //create response
        var response: DevotionalResponse = DevotionalResponse()
        fillInResponse(response)

        //write it to a Bundle
        var newBundle: Bundle = Bundle()
        newBundle.putParcelable(DEVOTIONAL_RESPONSE, response)

        //read it from the new Bundle
        var newResponse: DevotionalResponse = newBundle.getParcelable(DEVOTIONAL_RESPONSE)

        //check that they're the same
        assert(newResponse.getDevotionals().get(0).getContent().equalsIgnoreCase(response.getDevotionals().get(0).getContent()))
    }
}
```

DevotionalResponse.kt

```
class DevotionalResponse() : Parcelable {

    @Expose
    var devotionals = arrayListOf<Devotional>();

    constructor(in: Parcel) : this() {
        in.readTypedList(this.devotionals, Devotional.CREATOR)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeTypedList(devotionals)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<DevotionalResponse>() {
            override fun createFromParcel(in: Parcel): DevotionalResponse =
                    DevotionalResponse(in)

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<DevotionalResponse?> =
                    arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Go on This Link For full Solution

[Kotlin Object Example](http://matthewwear.xyz/kotlin-android-and-parcelable-a-journey-of-a-thousand-bundles/)

Comment: @Miha_x64 yaaa but you can do it in kotlin

Comment: Oh, I've never noticed it's in Java. Switching between Kotlin and Java is absolutely seamless for me. :)

Comment: @Miha_x64  plzzz solve this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361960/how-to-put-recyclerview-onitemclicklistener-on-fragment